# Elasticsearch Java API Function Score and script Query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, opensearch

I want to write the query to hit from java. But didn't get proper documentation. Can someone please help?

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "size": 2,
  "query": {
    "script_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "color": "RED"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "lang": "knn",
        "source": "knn_score",
        "params": {
          "field": "my_binary",
          "query_value": "iiQ1QDEABAA=",
          "space_type": "hammingbit"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @james-z could you please help me with this. I would be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do it:

```
// Build the query part
TermQueryBuilder termQuery = QueryBuilders.termQuery("color", "RED");

// Build the script
Map params = new HashMap();
params.put("field", "my_binary");
params.put("query_value", "iiQ1QDEABAA=");
params.put("space_type", "hammingbit");
Script script = new Script(ScriptType.STORED, null, "knn_score", params);

// Assemble the two together
ScriptScoreQueryBuilder scriptScoreBuilder = QueryBuilders.scriptScoreQuery(termQuery, script);

// Build the query
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(); 
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder(); 
searchSourceBuilder.query(scriptScoreBuilder); 
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
```

Comment: Hi @Val, I have tried it but the knn_score script is not getting recognized. I have tried with high-level clients. I will check with a low-level client for java and will let you know. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hi Val, It worked with the low-level client by using JSON query. We built a manual query for that.

Comment: Weird, the code above should work as well